# Showing chrome console contents on actual webpage

Tags: javascript, html, firebase-realtime-database

I want to show those results on chrome console within that 'Canteen' tag but I'm failing to do that. Have tried using a list id [Chrome console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2ZEV.jpg).

**This is code:**

```js
var database = firebase.database();
var msgRef = firebase.database().ref('survey');

msgRef.on("child_added",function(snapshot) {
  var changedPost = snapshot.val();
  console.log(changedPost)  
});

var ids = 'IDs: ';
$('[show_survey]').each(function () {
    ids += this.id + ' ';
});

$('#results').text(ids);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "survey" style="background:white;float:center;height:70%;width:80%;margin:10%;border-radius:20px;">
  <h1 id="fireHeading" align="center">CANTEEN SURVEY</h1>
  <div id = "contact" style="margin-right:50%;">
    <p>
      <ul id = "show_survey"></ul>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('[show_survey]')` will locate and reference the one and only `ul` in your HTML. Using `.each()` on it will then attempt to loop through all the `ul`s found, but there is only one. Then, inside your `.each()` all you are doing is building a string that is then placed inside of `#results`, but you don't have an element with that `id`. You also don't have (nor is there such a thing) as a `Canteen tag`. Do you mean the `h1` with the `id` of `fireHeading`?

Answer (score 1):

You can override the default implementation of console.log()

What your doing is basically, overriding your default implementation of `console.log()`.

Explanation of the code: 
You check for console logs in your script in the if condition and if so retrieve the log and put it to old variable. 
Then you declare another variable called logger and link it to your HTML div tag called log. 
Further more it will check the message is an object. If it's an object, it will stringify (convert the JSON object to string) and return the value to logger variable. Otherwise if it's not an object, that means its already a string. Therefore in the else statement it will return the message variable to the logger variable. And logger variable will post as div log in the HTML content.

You could try a function like the one given below.

```js
(function () {
    if (!console) {
        console = {};
    }
    var old = console.log;
    var logger = document.getElementById('log');
    console.log = function (message) {
        if (typeof message == 'object') {
            logger.innerHTML += (JSON && JSON.stringify ? JSON.stringify(message) : String(message)) + '<br />';
        } else {
            logger.innerHTML += message + '<br />';
        }
    }
})();

console.log("ChangePost Value");
```

```html
<div id="survey" style="background:white;float:center;height:70%;width:80%;margin:10%;border-radius:20px;">
  <h1 id="fireHeading" align="center">CANTEEN SURVEY</h1>
  <div id="contact" style="margin-right:50%;">
    <div id="log"></div>
    <p>
      <ul id="show_survey">
      </ul>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you further explain the code and why it functions?

Comment: I have updated according to your question. but removed the firebase logs. Sure give me a min to edit the answer with explanations.

Comment: @Gorgamite glad to help out and tick the answer if this helps you as well. Thanks

Comment: *You can override the default implementation of console.log()* But, you shouldn't. Just place each message in an array and then output the array contents to the `console` as well as the HTML element.